# Draw ellipse axis

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot an ellipse and its axis in a pgfplots axis. I tried using cross out but then it is diagonally crossed instead of horizontally and vertically. The axis I want are just straight lines without any label nor arrow. Could any one tell me how to do this please ?
I would like to start with that minimal example and add something for axis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=4, ymin=0, ymax=3, width=\textwidth, height=0.5\textwidth]

\draw [draw, thick] (axis cs:1.7,1.2) ellipse [x radius=0.009, y radius=0.003, rotate=80, xscale=15, yscale=30];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Do you want to plot the ellipse or draw it?

Comment: I don't know,what is the difference? I only know the semi-axis length and the angle to draw it.

Comment: What about the major axis?

Comment: The major and minor axis are known but as I use "scale", I can't just draw the axis. I could rescale everything before plotting/drawing but that would be long, I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of the intended result.

Here is a plot of an ellipse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,height=6cm,trig format plots=rad,variable=t]
\addplot[red,thick,domain=-2*pi:2*pi,samples=200]
({10*cos(t)},{sin(t)});
\draw (0,1) -- (0,-1) (-10,0) -- (10,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for that answer. The result looks like what I want but I want to draw it knowing only the semi-axis length and the rotation angle. And I would like to draw the axis without computing the coordinates myself (like (0,1), etc.).