# Graphing abs(xy)=2 with tikz. Error

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to graph |xy|=2 in tikz. Please consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}% coordinates
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        ymax=3, ymin=-3, ylabel={$y$},
        xmax=3, xmin=-3, xlabel={$x$},
        ytick distance=1,
        xtick distance=1
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And when I do this

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}% coordinates
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        ymax=3, ymin=-3, ylabel={$y$},
        xmax=3, xmin=-3, xlabel={$x$},
        ytick distance=1,
        xtick distance=1
        ]
        \addplot{abs(x*y)=2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I end up with this error: `Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator` =' or `=2' (in 'abs(x*y)=2'). \addplot{abs(x*y)=2};`

Comment: I don't believe `pgf` can handle implicit equations.  You'll need to solve this for y.

Comment: Using PSTricks there is a direct command called `\psplotImp` for the implicit functions.

Comment: If you can parameterized it, then TikZ can draw it directly. [see for example the ellipse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215685/108724).

Comment: anyway draw it twice: y=2/x and y=-2/x.

Answer (score 2):

`pgf` is not able to plot implicit equations.  For most implicit equations, this can't be fixed.  In your case, however, we just need to solve for `y=±2/x` (and also account for the singularity in the domain):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}% coordinates
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        ymax=3, ymin=-3, ylabel={$y$},
        xmax=3, xmin=-3, xlabel={$x$},
        ytick distance=1,
        xtick distance=1
        ]
        \addplot[domain=-3:-.3]{2/x};
        \addplot[domain=.3:3]{2/x};
        \addplot[domain=-3:-.3]{-2/x};
        \addplot[domain=.3:3]{-2/x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! Is this the same for graphs like |x|+|y|=2?

Comment: Yes.  You need to solve for `y`, and plot from there.  I usually need to know what the function is going to look like before I can turn to TeX.  For your example, I would need to get to `y=±(2-|x|)` and plot from there.  It might even be easier to plot `(0,-2)--(2,0)--(0,2)--(-2,0)--cycle`.